# Itext PdfSmartCopy getting Null pointer Exception

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm now using Itext PdfSmartCopy. I'm adding some business contents to a document object with XMLworker. Then I declared a reader (for a pdf file to be concatenated to this document object). Then I'm calling PdfSmartCopy with the same document object and output file stream as arguments. Then I'm using conventional steps to copy the page to the document,

```
addHTML(document, htmlStringToBeAdded);
document.newPage();
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy copy = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream("c:\\pdf_issue\\bad_itext3.pdf"));
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader reader=new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader("c:\\pdf_issue\\bad1.pdf");
 // loop over the pages in that document
 n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
  for (int page = 0; page < n; ) {
                copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
            }
copy.freeReader(reader);
    reader.close();
```

But I'm getting Null pointer exception at getPageReference? What's the issue?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.getPageReference(PdfWriter.java:1025)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.getCurrentPage(PdfWriter.java:1043)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy.addPage(PdfCopy.java:356)
    at com.jci.util.PdfTest.main(PdfTest.java:627)
```

But this piece works well if I use a new document object ie without adding business contents.

Comment: It would help to look at the pdf or it fails with any document?

Comment: Hi @PauloSoares, please take a look at https://jira.itextsupport.com/browse/DEV-1256 if you want an example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Hi @Bruno, I can't access the above link. Can you please help me on how I can get rid of this exception?

Comment: The above link is for customers only. Are you a customer?

Comment: Nope, any suggestions for this issue?

Comment: Document.open() method shall be called just after you create PdfCopy/PdfSmartCopy instance. Otherwise document is not properly initialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had a similar question in our closed issue tracker. In that ticket, it appeared that the `Document` needed to be opened right after the `PdfCopy` instance is created.

In your case, we see a similar problem: you use a `Document` object to create a PDF from scratch, and you then use *the same* `Document` to create a copy of an existing PDF. That can never work: you need to close the document you create from scratch first, and then create a new `Document` for the copy process:

```
// first create the document
Document document = new Document();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
document.open();
addHTML(document, htmlStringToBeAdded);
document.close();
// Now you can use the document you've just created
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(baos.toArray());
PdfReader existing = new PdfReader("c:\\pdf_issue\\bad1.pdf");
document = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream("c:\\pdf_issue\\bad_itext3.pdf"));
document.open();
copy.addDocument(reader);
copy.addDocument(existing);
document.close();
reader.close();
existing.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno. This makes sense and gives me the solution exactly that  I'm looking for. Let me try it.